# Create keys without writing them to disk?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

## Preamble

I was digging deep into the .Net [x509certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [x509certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) objects noticed that both the certificate classes serialize the private key to disk by default due to the verifiable use of Persist-Key options in the constructors of the x509certificate2 and x509certificate classes using a default option set for CspProviderFlags that does not include CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey.  This is verifiable via any number of web sites that show the source for .Net as well as with a copy of resharper should you choose to do it yourself.

Looking further, In fact these .Net objects simply seem to be wrappers for a central old style crypto32.dll cryptographic context.  What worries me about this is that looking at the code deeper I find that it seems to explicitly look in an on-disk file storage for public and private keys in the getters and setters for the PublicKey field on the x509certificate2 and x509certificate object.. despite the fact that I would otherwise expect them to only exist in memory.  Based on this knowledge it seems to store my private key in this storage even if I do not want it to do so, because the constructor does not allow you to change this option and turn it off based on the constructor list I am seeing when I look at the documentation; So if you set() or get() from the PrivateKey field it is really just collecting it from this file store behind the scenes.

## Reason for my question

I think that being forced to leak my private key to the file system - even temporally - is a huge security issue so I do not want to do it.  I also do not trust the certificate store.  Even if you disagree with me,  I personally believe that being forced to serialize my private key to disk even if I do not intend to do so is a huge security issue, so I do not want to do it.

## Goal

My current goal is to simply be able to generate RSA public and private X509 keys in C# that can be used on windows without needing to be forced to write them to the hard disk as part of the creation process, and I am not finding many valid options as all of the ones I can find seem to have either hidden gaps or publicly known issues.

The goal is not to never write them to disk, it is just to not do so unless its with code I have written and know to be secure to make sure they are fully encrypted at rest; ie, it should not do so unless I explicitly ask for it after the keys themselves have been fully encrypted.

## Goal tldr;

In short: I want to write secure software on windows using C# to generate a 509 certificate that doesn't force me to export, import, or otherwise leak my private key to the file system as part of the certificate creation.  I want to be able to create my own X509Certificates on windows using as little third party code as possible.

## Options I have considered

1. The Standard .Net types as stated have been looked at in depth and found to be lacking due to the above issues. I just don't have enough access to the internal CSP settings as the constructors and access do not expose them, and the defaults used as what I would personally consider to be insecure.
2. The [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/%20%22Bouncy%20Castle%27) library looked like a good option at first, but it actively exposes my public and private keys to the file system just lie the normal .net types do when it converts them to the standard .Net types since these objects store things behind the scenes without asking BC if its ok first..
3. I attempted to find a crypto32.dll p-invoke option that would allow me to not serialize my keys, only to find that all I could find did exactly that even when I did not want them to. And finding data on it was very difficult so I mostly just looked at the source code only to find that it didn't seem to like me trying to not store keys.
4. I am unable to find any other options despite spending several days researching this topic.  Even Stack Overflow says to use BC or the native typesd in most cases; yet that doesn't solve my problem.

## Question

How would I best create my own X509 Certificates without doing any of the following as I feel they are all security issues:

1. The use of makecert.exe requires I allow my process execute rights on the server so it can start a process; thats a security issue waiting to happen. Not to mention, I cant audit the code and I am willing to bet its still storing the keys in the cert store even If I do not want them to be.
2. The use of the C#/.Net x509certificate2 and x509certificate objects serialize a generated public key to disk by default via its calls to the Certificate Store so that's not an option; The goal is to do things in a secure manner, and so the idea of all the private keys I'm generating being stored on disk for just anybody to access them doesn't leave me with good feelings. ANd its very hard to find data on the cert store; thus I cant validate its security and have to consider it not a valid option.
3. The use of third party libs such as Bouncy Castle creates update scenarios and the possibility of a third party that has to be trusted, creating an even larger attack surface; and sadly they all use the same conversions that are affected by what I am personally calling the "hidden private key store" issue of them trying to play nice with the standard System.Security.Cryptography API by using the same objects that have this leaking key issue.  So If in general we want to keep the system as secure as possible.. that sort of leak is not an option.

Comment: "I also do not trust the certificate store" - then why trust *any* third party code - why not write it all from scratch if you're not going to trust OS provided security services?

Comment: Time Constraints.  Also, I'm looking for a new perspective and aware that I do not know everything so I thought I would ask.

Comment: And yet you're somehow "aware" that the private keys being stored is a big issue, despite the fact that if it was an issue, it would be a **huge** issue that everyone would be shouting about?

Comment: Well, I'm shouting about it now.

Comment: So, you're working in .NET, and I'm assuming you're going to fix your second paragraph where you express a desire where the keys should only exist on disk rather than on disk. How are you going to stop the OS from paging your entire process (including its keys) into the page file?

Comment: Updated post to reflect the error you saw.

As far as paging goes, that's just a system setting, and easy enough to stop if you set up a RAM based virtual HDD that is used for the Swap files so that the data is never serialized to disk.

Comment: So, you're in a highly constrained environment where you can dictate such requirements as an RAM based "swap", but you're unable to guarantee the security of the file system? That makes **no** sense.

Comment: The file system is encrypted; that is easy.  That said I want to know how do do this, so I am asking. I don't need a reason to want to know.

Comment: If you want to really protect your private key data, then simply don't create it on machine. Use a HSM or a smart card (for lower availability keys) instead. And make sure access to that hardware module is adequately protected of course. Otherwise, at least make sure your libraries are FIPS compliant.

Comment: FIPS is a joke.. you can be FIPS compliant and be insecure due to the use of the weak crypto that FIPS allows.

Comment: @honestduane Not everything that is FIPS compliant is automatically secure, that's certainly true. But it does have some requirements with regards to key storage and destruction.

Comment: That is just it; this doesn't seem to be FIPS compliant as the keys are leaked.

Comment: You might want to have a look at PolarSSL (https://polarssl.org/). To use it in C# you would have to implement P/invoke wrappers to call the library routines. But the code is very readable and short - much easier to comprehend than Bouncy Castle. It should be very easy to just extract the PolarSSL coded needed for your purpose.

Comment: I am not sure about your concern regarding BouncyCastle. It may need to store in the file system only if you want to convert BouncyCastle types to .NET crypto types. But why do you want to do it? You can do all kind of crypto operation with BouncyCastle itself.

Comment: Also what about OpenSSL.NET?

Comment: My 2 cents, if you need to be that secure do not use .net, if you care about leaking to disk you probably care about code injection and memory isolation bypassing, which is a huge issue in .net as it's really easy to do (I let you google that). Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Without going super-low-level (or disabling paging altogether) you can't guarantee that your private key material is never written to disk, because it can always be paged out. Even then, on a system that supports hibernation your key will be present in the hibernation file.

The crypt32 key storage mechanism uses DPAPI (user or machine scoped, depending on your import flags and/or flags in the PFX) to encrypt the key material at rest. So while it is involving the filesystem, it isn't "stored on disk for just anybody to access them"; unless they're running as you, or have permission to access the system keys.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, if you are this concerned and not willing to trust anyone/any outside APIs then you are going to have to use a lower level language than .Net. .Net is a great RAD type language, but if you don't trust the machine you are running on, you will want the lowest level environment you can achieve.

C would be a good option.